# How to have one AsyncTask for all my db calls

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am looking for the right way of designing my app here.

I have 5 activities and each one calls a separate DB method (update, insert, delete ..etc).
I was wondering, instead of creating 5 asynctask classes, each is a private class belonging to the activity to be called from, is there way I can create one asynctask class so I instantiate its object in all the activities?

In C++, you can pass "an entire method" to be executed so  Ican create an assign task and pass a method to it to be executed, but I am not sure I can do that in Java. Or what would be the best practice in your mind?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Runnable` class.

A `Runnable` represents a task that can be executed. You need to implement it's `run()` You can pass an instance of `Runnable` to your `AsyncTask` and execute it in it's `doInBackground(...)` method.

There might be a better way to do this, but this is the only thing that is comming to my mind right now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think a runnable executes in it's own thread.  Using a runnable should eliminate the need for AsyncTask.

Comment: I agree with Jason,runnable kinda of elimnate the use of asynctask

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would fit your bill but I would recommend creating an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), that would automatically and asynchronously queue up your Database/Content-Provider read and writes.

You can write separate read, write and update methods that will be handled in the onHandleIntent method of the IntentService. The Intent service insures that

- the database/CP access is done asynchronously
- successive database/CP access requests are automatically queued and handled
- the Service is stopped/started automatically, no need to manage the lifecycle
- the database/CP read/write is done even if the app goes into the background

For ListView/Adapter access, consider using [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is indeed a different way of doing things. It is certainly more complicated and not really what I want to deal with. Hoever +1 for the smart suggestion